# Copy rows of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1','2','3'), b = c('b1', '', 'b3'), c = c('c1', 'c2', ''), d = c('d1', '', ''))

id b   c   d
1  b1  c1  d1
2      c2 
3  b3
```

where the row with `id-1` is filled with all data with no empty column values. I want to copy all cell values from `id-1` into `id 2 and 3` if there are missing values in those cells from `rows 2 & 3`. Final output something like:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c('1','2','3'), b = c('b1', 'b1', 'b3'), c = c('c1', 'c2', 'c1'), d = c('d1', 'd1', 'd1'))

id b   c   d
1  b1  c1  d1
2  b1  c2  d1
3  b3  c1  d1
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some matrix indexing to get the `""` cases and then overwrite selecting the appropriate column from the first row of `df`:

```
idx <- which(df[-1]=="", arr.ind=TRUE)
df[-1][idx] <- unlist(df[1,-1][idx[,"col"]])

#  id  b  c  d
#1  1 b1 c1 d1
#2  2 b1 c2 d1
#3  3 b3 c1 d1
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. Works perfect. I had a follow up question. what is I took the row with `id - 1` and stored it in a different dataframe (`df2`). What can I do to copy those columns with `"" or NAs`?

Comment: @DigvijaySawant - you should be able to replace `df[1,-1]` with just `df2` if I understand correctly.