# Copy selective row values from 1 dataframe to another in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:`df <- data.frame(id = c('1','2','3'), b = c('b1', 'NA', 'b3'), c = c('c1', 'c2', 'NA'), d = c('d1', 'NA', 'NA'))`

```
id b   c   d
1  b1  c1  d1
2  NA  c2  NA
3  b3  NA  NA
```

I have extracted values with `id = 1` from `df` to another dataframe say `df2` so `df2` has 1 row

```
id b c d
1 b1 c1 d1
```

I need to copy all values from `df2 to df1` wherever there is not an `NA` in `df1`
Result Table:

```
id b   c   d
1  b1  c1  d1
2  b1  c2  d1
3  b3  c1  d1
```

Thank you in advance. I asked similar question before but deleting it.

Comment: Do you mean wherever there IS a `NA` in a row?

Comment: What is the rule being followed here? Why is `df2[3,3]` `c1` instead of `c2`?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205583/filtering-data-in-a-dataframe-based-on-criteria

Comment: Isn't this just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937431/copy-rows-of-dataframes-in-r/50937532 with an `is.na` test instead of `==""` ?

Comment: @thelatemail I have tried with is.na and get an error saying `Error in if (length(o)%%N != 0L) warning("number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` I just replaced line `idx <- which(is.na(df[-1]), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: @user32185 Yes. Just replace the NA and if there exists a value in that cell keep it as it is.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Yes you are correct. Sorry it was a typo

Comment: `"NA"` is not the same as `NA`  - which makes this confusing. Try `df[-1]=='NA'` and it will work perfectly. You should try to work with actual `NA` / missing values though, as they have special features that the string `"NA"` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment that `df2[3,3]` should be `c2` and not `c1`, a straightforward answer is to use `zoo::na.locf`.

```
library(zoo)
df2 <- na.locf(df)

#   id  b  c  d
# 1  1 b1 c1 d1
# 2  2 b1 c2 d1
# 3  3 b3 c2 d1
```

---

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("b1", NA, "b3"), c = c("c1", 
"c2", NA), d = c("d1", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you. Never heard of this package.seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a mistake in your question -> df2 will be equal to b1-c1-d1 not b1-c2-d1, here is the solution :

Initialize dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1','2','3'), b = c('b1', 'NA', 'b3'), c = c('c1', 'c2', 'NA'), d = c('d1', 'NA', 'NA'))
```

Converting string NAs to actual detectable NAs

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) { gsub("NA", NA, x) }))
```

Obtaining default value row

```
df2<-df[df$id==1,]
```

For all rows, check if the column cell is na, then fill it with the df2 cell of the same column

```
for (r in 1:nrow(df)) for( c in colnames(df)) df[r,c]<-ifelse(is.na(df[r,c]),as.character(df2[1,c]),as.character(df[r,c]))
```